# standard Taylor series using substitution

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

Find Taylor series using substitution about $0$ for $f(x)=\frac{125}{(5+4x)^3}$ by writing $\frac{125}{(5+4x)^3}=\frac{1}{(1+\frac{4}{5}x)^3}$?

Determine a range of validity for this series.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Start with Taylor expansion $$\frac{1}{1+y}=1-y+y^2-y^3+y^4-y^5+O\left(y^6\right)$$ Rise to the third power to obtain  $$\frac{1}{(1+y)^3}=1-3 y+6 y^2-10 y^3+15 y^4-21 y^5+O\left(y^6\right)$$ Now, replace $y$ by $\frac{4 x}{5}$ to get your result.

I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: instead of taking third power of series,taking third times derivatives more easy, a suggestion

Comment: I totally agree with you. Post this as an answer; claim that this is simpler than what I did. I shall upvote your answer. Cheers.

Comment: So you mean that I missed something,well. Can you show that How can you take third power of the series? I can not see 
a simple way.

Comment: @mesel. Not at all. I said that your comment is very positive and that you must put it as an answer claiming that your approach is much simpler than mine. Cheers.

Comment: I wrote it as an answer:)

Comment: Thank you, using this answerand the fact that 1+4x=5+4(x-1) I had to find the Taylors series about 1 for g which is 125/(1+4x)^3

Answer (score 1):

As Claude did,
$$\frac{1}{1+y}=1-y+y^2-y^3+y^4-y^5+...+(-1)^ny^n...$$ and take second derivative of this expension to get,

$$ \frac{2}{(1+y)^3}=(\frac{1}{1+y})^{''}=2-6y+12y^2-20y^3...n(n-1)(-1)^ny^{n-2}...$$

$$\frac{1}{(1+y)^3}=1-3y+6y^2-10y^3...{n\choose2}(-1)^{n+1}y^{n-2}... $$

Then replace $y$ by $4x\over5$ then you will get your series.

Since above expension convergent for $|y|<1$ your expension is convergent for $|{4x\over5}|<1$

Comment: Thank you, I have managed this one I am now stuck on checking my answer to my Taylor series. By finding first, second and third derivatives of g and using these to find the cubic Taylor polynomial about 1 for g.I am stuck on finding first 4 derivatives of 125/((1+4x)^3)?

Answer (score -1):

you have $(1+4/5x)^{-3}$=1-12/5x+64/25$x^2$.....
is the required exxpansion about x=0. for range, its true for |4/5x|<1

Comment: I do not think it is true for all $x$.

Comment: Such a series of course only converges when $|4/5\,x|<1$.

Comment: @ketan: it is not since you must require $|4/5x|<1$ you can get it by ratio test.

Comment: @mesel, was its radius of convergence, R=1??

Comment: @ketan: it is radius of convergency of expension of $\frac{1}{1+y}$